# Google don't track my location anymore

Tags: gps, google-maps, gps-tracking

I was using location history all the time, on one quick walk when I took photos with my DSLR I've notice that my location was way off from my walk so I've set in settings for my location to use only GPS (no WiFi and no GSM data) and now when I check my location for that day there was no tracking. I've set it back to all data, but still no location for second day.

In mean time I've installed GPS Logger application.

How can I make my tracking working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the settings to HIGH ACCURACY and turn on 'google location history' and restart(reboot) the phone.

Comment: Thanks it works, so if you change GPS settings you need to restart your phone (I use GPS only and it give more accurate results).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the solution is to get it working for you again, but I can say that setting location to GPS only does not ensure that it will actually look for your location via GPS, it just means that it will only ever log your location based on GPS. This means that, when you're out traveling somewhere and you use an app that has permissions to access GPS data, that app will enable GPS and use it (such as Google Maps), then Google will create the log of the location data while GPS was on. However, the moment an app finishes using GPS, Google is no longer logging data because you aren't using GPS anymore. This is done to save battery on the device.

If you want to test this, you could use a GPS app (like a different map software, to ensure that the location data isn't just being shared from Google Maps to your location history), ensure the app is actually turning GPS on, and then check whether Google has logged that location data at the end of the day.

Comment: I think you're right yesterday I had GPS option on with GPS logger and I have location history from yesterday but today I was not using the app and no location for today (unless it update next day but I doubt it).